# Output 4 days in weatherdata xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to import XML data via XSLT into Adobe InDesign. I want to get information for the next four days (not today). So far I've only been able to get for tomorrows forecast but am not sure how to output four days. The template selects day 2 (tomorrow) and time period 2 (time of day)

I have access to free weather data in this format: http://www.yr.no/place/Iceland/Capital_Region/Reykjavik/forecast.xml

This is the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" cdata-section-elements=""/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--
  The position of the time[@period = '2'] element; indexing starts from 1.
  You can pass in this parameter to the transformation if you want the
  time[@period = '1'] element in some other position.
  -->
  <xsl:param name="time" select="2"/> <!-- This is the day -->
  <xsl:param name="base" select="'file:///Volumes/Media/Geymsla/ymis_verkefni/DV2013/sky/'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <yr>
      <testtag>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="weatherdata"/>
      </testtag>
    </yr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="weatherdata">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="location/name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="links/link[@id = 'overview']"/>
    <base><xsl:value-of select="$base"/></base>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="meta/lastupdate"/>
    <!-- Apply the <time period="2"> element in $time position, the time of day -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="forecast/tabular/time[@period = '2'][number($time)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tabular/time">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="symbol"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="precipitation"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="temperature"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="windSpeed"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="windDirection"/>

    <!--
    Use attribute value template (AVT) to construct the attribute value:
    http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#attribute_value_templates
    -->
    <Image href="{concat($base, symbol/@var, '.png')}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="location/name">
    <title>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="links/link">
    <alternate>
      <!-- Use the value of the @url attribute of this element -->
      <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
    </alternate>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="temperature">
    <tempval>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </tempval>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="windSpeed">
    <speedname>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </speedname>

    <speedmps>
      <xsl:value-of select="@mps"/>
    </speedmps>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="windDirection">
    <dirdeg>
      <xsl:value-of select="@deg"/>
    </dirdeg>

    <dircode>
      <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
    </dircode>

    <dirname>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </dirname>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="precipitation">
    <precip>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </precip>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="symbol">
    <symbolvar>
      <xsl:value-of select="@var"/>
    </symbolvar>

    <symbolnr>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </symbolnr>

    <symbolname>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </symbolname>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lastupdate">
    <!-- Copy the original node as is -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your predicate filter. You are currently selecting all of the `time` elements who's `@period=2`, and then you are sub-selecting from those matched elements the second one:

```
<!-- Apply the <time period="2"> element in $time position, the time of day -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="forecast/tabular/time[@period = '2'][number($time)]"/>
```

In order to select the `@period` specified by the `$time` parameter you would use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="forecast/tabular/time[@period = number($time)]"/>
```

Then you can filer for the next four days by applying a predicate fitler on that set:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="forecast/tabular/time[@period = number($time)]
                                       [position() > 1 and position() &lt;= 5]"/>
```